# Not being able to copy text from Vim to system clipboard but able to paste from system clipboard to vim in Linux

Tags: linux, vim, copy-paste

I am using Linux OS. I would like to copy some text in visual mode from Vim to system clipboard and then paste it in another shell. I tried the following :

In the .*vimrc* file inside */home/{USER}* directory put the following :

```
vmap <C-c> "*y
```

After this I exited the shell and then opened a new shell and a file in vim. Did Visual selection and then issued *y. It yanked the lines selected. I exited vim and then in the shell  issued <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+V</kbd> . But nothing happens.

I tried setting the following also in .vimrc file  :

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

But this also doesn't work.

P.S: I am *able* to paste from system clipboard to vim using `*p`.

What can be the problem here? Am I setting the options in the *wrong* .vimrc file?

**Edit**: When I did vim --version|grep clipboard I see the following:

```
[subhrcho@slc04lyo ~]$ vim --version|grep clipboard
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

Comment: This is the right `~/.vimrc`. Try `"+y` and `"+p` instead.

Comment: @romainl `*p` works for me already.

Comment: Are you running vim within the terminal or the GUI version?  What does `vim --version | grep clipboard` say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, there's a difference between `"*` and `"+`. If you want to use the system clipboard (e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>), you have to use `"+`. (Likewise, there's a `:set clipboard+=unnamedplus` in recent Vim versions.)

To paste the contents of `"*` in a terminal, use the *middle mouse button*.

Read more about this at `:help x11-selection`

Comment: @Igno I tried your suggestion. When inside Vim , if I do `+y` I see vim yanks some lines. And next I quit vim by `:q!` and then in the shell I do a right click, I see both copy and paste context menus are disabled. The CTRL+SHIFT+V also doesn't work.

Comment: As per your edit, you first need to use a Vim that has clipboard support compiled in. Without that, you need to resort to external solutions like `xclip`.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't paste with `"*p` if Vim was not build with clipboard support.

`-clipboard` and `-xterm_clipboard` mean "no clipboard". Without clipboard support, `"*y`, `"+y`, `"*p` and `"+p` can't paste to/from the clipboard *at all*.

If you want clipboard support, you must get yourself a proper Vim build (`vim-gtk` for example). It's as simple as that.